# IE 7, 8, 9 js position issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am building a website, that is currently sitting here:

http://s398928181.websitehome.co.uk/Ivyproperties/index.html

When I view it IE 7, 8 or 9 the top section with  logo and nav appears outside of the main content. Also the fading image gallery does the same. Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Might be worth posting some code?

Comment: just posting a link to a *potentially* malicious site? No one would dare enter.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Ivy Properties</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js'></script>
<script src='js/example.js'></script>
<script src='js/slideshow.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="nav-wrap">
<ul class="group" id="nav">
<li class="current_page_item">
<a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: <div id="header">
<div id="logo">Ivy Properties</div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
<img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
<img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
<img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
<img src="images/image5.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 5" />
<img src="images/image6.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 6" />
<img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 7" />
<img src="images/image8.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 8" />
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the filter applied to div#wrapper.

The shadow produced with this property adds to the elements width. Unlike box-shadow.

I suggest just leaving it that way. People who visit your site with old Browsers won't notice they miss a shadow (as long as they don't do a side by side comparison with any other browser, which is highly unlikely)

Comment: Great thanks, that has sorted the problem